# Grails 2.0 issue rendering FancyBox

Tags: grails, fancybox, grails-2.0, fancybox-2

Using Grails 2.0.4 and FancyBox 2.

I am trying to render html in a modal or dialog popup in the grails framework.  Currently I am attempting to do this with FancyBox 2.  However I cannot seem to render the fancybox.  Here is what I currently have.

Controller:

```
class TestController {

def index() { }

def createResult() {
    render 'got here dude'
}
```

}

Exert from gsp:

```
    <body>
    //attempts to use fancy box but fails 
    <a class="fb" href="${createLink(action: 'createResult', controller: 'test') }" >Click Here</a>
    //not fancy box, renders page only
    <a class="not" href="${createLink(action: 'createResult', controller: 'test') }" >Click Here2</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fb").fancybox();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

By clicking on the top link I end up getting the following error:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /ModalTest/test/createResult

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work with grails or have another dialog/modal solution that will work by utilizing the controller?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the error happening in your JavaScript or is that a server side error?  My guess is client side.  fancybox is probably looking at the href and doesn't know what to do with it.  Are you trying to open a modal dialog with text in the body that comes from the server?

Comment: I just looked at the FancyBox docs and I think I know what you're trying to do.  What if you just put the generated link in as the href instead of letting Grails do it via the createLink tag and see what happens.  What you're doing seems like it should work.  Now just have to backtrack and go as simple as possible then work your way forward.

Comment: @Gregg Error is happening in the javascript.  If i understand you correctly here is what I tried: <a class="fb" href="test/createResult" >Click Here4</a>.  Interesting this way I do get the fancy box to popup however it is the basic error that it could not get the data.  It does not hit the method on the controller.  If I use the exact same code but replace the class, so as not to hit the fancy box, it works as expected.

Comment: If I find some time later tonight I'll see if I can create a blank project and test this myself.

Comment: @Gregg Do you have any other suggestions besides fancybox?  I tried the modal window that comes with twitter bootstrap, but ran into a different issue there.  That brought me to fancybox.  I am not sold on fancy box, just need a solution to display some html formatted text in a popup window!

Comment: I primarily use Bootstrap these days.  I was using jQueryUI in the past. Both of which I've had to write wrappers around to have them display dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

Add class **fancybox.ajax**, this should work, since you are trying to load ajax content:

```
<a class="fb fancybox.ajax" href="${createLink(action: 'createResult', controller: 'test') }" >Click Here</a>
```